# ThreeJS Dynamic Line Change

Tags: javascript, three.js

In ThreeJS, I have a rotating cube which consists of a bunch of particles. The particles are part of a particle array called particles, and they are also part of a group called group which is rotating around the origin on the x, y, and z. I was wondering how to connect two particles with a line dynamically. The code I currently have to try and do this is below, and it doesn't work.

```
        var geometry2 = new THREE.Geometry();

            linemat = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
                color: 0xffffff
            });
            geometry2.vertices.push(particles[4].position);
            geometry2.vertices.push(particles[1000].position);  
            geometry2.update;           
            line = new THREE.Line(geometry2, linemat);
            scene.add(line);
```

This is inside of my render loop. However, it only draws one line where the particles *were*. As the cube rotates, the line just stays in space, not touching the points. It won't update, either.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Building on your current thinking, I would create the line outside of your render loop, then update its geometry inside your render loop. Note that to tell a `Geometry` that its vertices are updated, you need to set the `verticesNeedUpdate` flag to `true` (r61). In your code above, you have a statement `geometry2.update` which doesn't do anything (it's not calling a method or updating a value, and the `update` property doesn't exist in any case).

Alternatively, you can just add the line to the group that is rotating, and it should rotate along with it.

Comment: Thanks. Just wondering, if I wanted to make the line coordinates from one part of the particle array to another, say from particles[10], particles[100] to particles[15],particles[120], how would I go about doing that? Basically, it would change the position of the line while getting rid of the old line.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking, but `geometry.vertices` is an array, and you can add or remove points from it if you want.

Comment: for (var i = geometry.vertices.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (geometry.vertices[i] == vertexToRemove) {
            geometry.vertices.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }